# Unit tests running in parallel in flutter when using GetIt

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, dependency-injection

I am writing an flutter App and I am using GetIt for dependency injection.

When I write unit tests, I do something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  group("tests", () {
    test("test1", () {
      GetIt.I.reset();
      GetIt.I.registerSingleton(MyDependency());

      // Some code using GetIt.I<MyDependency>()
    });
    test("test2", () {
      GetIt.I.reset();
      GetIt.I.registerSingleton(MyDependency());

      // Some code using GetIt.I<MyDependency>()
    });
  });
}
```

When I run the tests one after the other, it works perfectly.

When I run all test at once, I get errors on the line `GetIt.I<MyDependency>()...` like this:

```
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory with  type HttpActions is not registered inside GetIt.
```

So my guess is, that the tests run in parallel and the setup of one test with `GetIt.I.reset()` conflicts with the setup of the other test.

So how can I solve  this?

- Can I somehow tell the tests, that they just cannot run in parallel?
- Or is there some way of safely using `GetIt` in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is not about running your tests in parallel but related to the fact that `GetIt.I.reset()` is an asynchronous method:

### Implementation

```dart
Future<void> reset({bool dispose = true});
```

And as mentionned in the [documentation of the package](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it/blob/master/lib/get_it.dart#L358) for this method:

> [...] As dispose functions can be async, you should await this function.

### Code Sample

I've made a new test sample based on the code you've provided and inspired by the [unit tests written for the package](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it/blob/master/test/get_it_test.dart) and it seems to be working properly.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:so_tests/my_dependency.dart';

void main() {
  // This method provided by `flutter_test` is called before each test.
  setUp(() async {
    // Make sure the instance is cleared before each test.
    await GetIt.I.reset();
  });

  group('tests', () {
    test('test1', () {
      final getIt = GetIt.instance;
      getIt.registerSingleton(MyDependency());

      // Some code using getIt<MyDependency>()
    });

    test('test2', () {
      final getIt = GetIt.instance;
      getIt.registerSingleton(MyDependency());

      // Some code using getIt<MyDependency>()
    });
  });
}
```